# How expire the pending delivery reports after few hours in kannel

Tags: kannel

I am using kannel as sms gateway, sometimes My end operator not proving any delivery repose for messages. All pending dlrs are queuing in my redis storage.

Is there anyway, expire the dlrs after couple hours without appending validity period while sending

Comment: Any solutions found ?

Comment: solved by looping all pending dlrs in every hour and checking the is expired or not

Comment: You mean having some script that looks in the dlr stored in the database and expiring them ?